# Windows VBox connect virtual+host from Lan

Tags: windows, virtualbox, lan

I have host OS "Windows 7 x64". I do start VBox with OS virtual "Windows 7 x86". Next, i do Bridge for my network interface:

[image: VBox Bridge]

Next, i setup ip4 address "192.168.56.5", where i have subnet "192.168.56.*"

[image: VBox ip4]

Next, my working subnet "192.168.0.*", and this routing real devices. I do settings new subnet (real adapter has addresses: 192.168.0.34 and 192.168.56.4):

[image: Two subnets on real device]

My virtual subnet not visible for working - this great! Next, i setup settings on virtual OS:

[image: Virtual ip4]

Virtual OS adapter has address 192.168.56.6. Ok, i see host, and host see virtual OS.

Next, a do ping on both OS:

[image: Pings]

It's working. Next, i try connecting from Sockets and it's fail... Connecting to MySQL DB on virtual OS - fail:

[image: MySQL Fail]

On virtual OS i can connecting to MySQL, and i see this DB. Similarly for sockets.

How do I configure the network? I need to connect to the virtual OS from sockets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now...

Problem has been solve. I did remove Virtual Network Interface, and all do works...

[image: Remove Virtual Network Interface]